# Rename named regions depending on worksheet they relate

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to rename my named regions(~400) to have their worksheet name as suffix.

How should I properly do this?

I have the following code now:

```
Sub ChangeNamedRegions()

    Dim oldRegionName  As String
    Dim newRegionName  As String

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
            ' If Range(n).Formula Like "=" + ws.Name + "*" Then
            If Range(n).Worksheet = ws Then
                oldRegionName = Range(n).Name
                newRegionName = ws.Name + oldRegionName

                ActiveWorkbook(oldRegionName).Name = newRegionName
                With ActiveWorkbook
                    .Names(oldRegionName).Delete
                End With

            End If
        Next n
    Next ws

End Sub
```

**Thanks in advance!**

**UPDATE**

Regions have workbook as their parent, not worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below would be simple and work.

```vb
Sub ChangeNamedRegions()
    Dim Name As Variant
    For Each Name In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If TypeOf Name.Parent Is Worksheet Then
            With Name
                .Name = .Parent.Name & Split(.Name, "!")(1)
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

One consideration is it won't work if sheet name has characters not available in a name of Name, such as spaces or brackets...

### Updated answer

If you need to use the name of worksheet which the defined name refers to, instead of the worksheet where the name is defined in, then you can use RefersToRange property of the name to get the referred to range, and then use Worksheet property of that range.

```vb
Sub ChangeNamedRegions()
    Dim Name As Name
    Dim ReferredToRange As Range
    For Each Name In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ReferredToRange = Name.RefersToRange
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ReferredToRange Is Nothing Then
            Name.Name = ReferredToRange.Worksheet.Name & Name.Name
        End If
        Set ReferredToRange = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that regions have workbook as their parent, not worksheet.